# Limit counter value after first loop cycle

Tags: php

How can I write this in such a way that $counter value is 1 on its first iteration and 0 on each following cycle?

```
$counter =1;

foreach($result):

 $number = $result['value'] + $counter;

 db->update($result['value'] => $number);

 $counter--;

endforeach;
```

Essentially my goal is to get $number to be $number+1 on the first loop and then $number+0 for each following loop.

The value of $result['value'] will be set after the first loop to $number+1, so on the next cycle $result['value'] will be the needed unchanged value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see where the problem resides.

```
$counter = 1;
foreach($result):
  $number = $result['value'] + $counter;
  // Once you have used your variable, just set it to zero...
  $counter = 0;
  db->update($result['value'] => $number);
endforeach;
```

Comment: Brilliant! The problem was clearly myself, over complicating the most basic of ideas. Thank you so much for giving me a fresh and obvious perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use something like this :

- test if `$counter` is `1`
- is yes, set it to `0`
- else, do nothing

Which would give you some code that would look like this :

```
$counter = 1;
foreach($result):
    $number = $result['value'] + $counter;
    db->update($result['value'] => $number);
    if ($counter == 1) {
        $counter = 0;
    }
endforeach;
```

Or, you could also just set `$counter` to `0` at the end of the loop, not testing anything :

```
$counter = 1;
foreach($result):
    $number = $result['value'] + $counter;
    db->update($result['value'] => $number);
    $counter = 0;
endforeach;
```

With this :

- The first time you are in the loop, `$counter` would be `1`, as initialized before the loop
- At the end of the first iteration, it would be set to `0`
- And it would then re-set to `0` after each iteration -- i.e. it would stay at `0`.

Comment: Yes, your second example is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. This is a clear case of working on days on end and not taking a break. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

the code looks like PHP although it is not syntactically valid.  I'll assume the iterated variable (here called `$results`) has numeric keys starting at 0:

```
foreach($results as $counter => $result):
    $number = $result['value'] + !$counter;
```

notice the negation.